# Unable to get data from Retrofit Call to a Direct JSON File

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on small project on a Jetpack Compose.
I am trying to data from a static JSON File from this url using Retrofit.
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/culoader.appspot.com/o/json%2Fcudata.json?alt=media&token=d0679703-2f6c-440f-af03-d4d61305cc84

**Network Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun proveidesCurrencyService() : CurrencyService{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CurrencyService::class.java)
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
interface CurrencyService {
    //@Streaming
    @GET
    suspend fun getCurrencyFile(@Url fileUrl:String): Response<ResponseBody>

}


data class CurrencyAPIResponse(

    @SerializedName("data") var data: MutableState<List<CurrencyRates>>

)

data class CurrencyRates (

    @SerializedName("code") var code : String,
    @SerializedName("value") var value : String

)
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class CurrencyDataViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val currencyService: CurrencyService
) : ViewModel() 
{
 init {
        getCurrencyFileData()
    }
}

 fun getCurrencyFileData() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val url: String =
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/culoader.appspot.com/o/json%2Fcudata.json?alt=media&token=d0679703-2f6c-440f-af03-d4d61305cc84"

        val responseBody = currencyService.getCurrencyFile(url).body()
        if (responseBody != null) {
            Log.d("\nresponsebody", responseBody.string())
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
            val currencyAPIResponse = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), CurrencyAPIResponse::class.java)
            val data: MutableState<List<CurrencyRates>> = currencyAPIResponse.data
            Log.d("Data", data.value[0].code)

        }

    }
```

Everytime, I am getting the below error,

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState com.tuts.playlite.network.response.CurrencyAPIResponse.getData()' on a null object reference*

Not sure, where I am failing, I have tried to convert this to JSON Object, but still failing. Is it right way to get the data?

Another thing noticed that even though the JSON file is complete in the url, the response body log is showing the JSON with some other content.

```
{
          "code": "IMP",
          "value": "0.722603"
        },
        {
          "code": "INR",
    
    [          1631385414.170 12452:12478 D/
     responsebody]
          "value": "72.99465"
        },
        {
          "code": "IQD",
          "value": "1458.61356"
        },
```

As a result, the GSON might not able to form the json and hence could be getting null exception.
Not sure why random text is getting added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the culprit seems to be responseBody Stream. After I changed the code with below, It seems to be working. I assume, it was unable to get the proper complete JSON earlier and throwing the null object reference error.

```
    val responseBody = currencyService.getCurrencyFile(url).body()
    val resData = responseBody?.byteStream()!!.bufferedReader().use {
        it.readText()
    }
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
    val currencyAPIResponse = gson.fromJson(resData, CurrencyAPIResponse::class.java)
```

Thank you for all support!

Answer (score 0):

You are already providing a Gson converter to retrofit, so retrofit should already be able to do the json to object conversion for you. That's the beauty of retrofit!

Try rewriting your CurrencyService like this:

```
interface CurrencyService {
    
    @GET("v0/b/culoader.appspot.com/o/json%2Fcudata.json?alt=media&token=d0679703-2f6c-440f-af03-d4d61305cc84")
    suspend fun getCurrencyFile(): CurrencyAPIResponse
}
```

Your ViewModel also has some issues. Not sure if you actually meant MutableState but I guess you're looking for MutableLiveData or MutableStateFlow. Below an example using MutableLiveData.

```
@HiltViewModel
class CurrencyDataViewModel @Injectconstructor(
private val currencyService: CurrencyService
) : ViewModel() {

  private val _currencyData = MutableLiveData<List<CurrencyRates>>()
  private val currencyData: LiveData = _currencyData

  init {
     getCurrencyFileData()
  }

  fun getCurrencyFileData() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     _currencyData.postValue(currencyService.getCurrencyFile().data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But now i get the below error.

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState<java.util.List<com.tuts.playlite.network.models.CurrencyRates>>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem*

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

Use Kotin Coroutines for retorfit, Try something like below

```
interface CurrencyService {
 @GET("v0/b/culoader.appspot.com/o/json%2Fcudata.json?alt=media&token=d0679703-2f6c-440f-af03-d4d61305cc84")
  suspend fun getCurrencyFile(): Response<CurrencyAPIResponse>
}
```

and if you are using MVVM use this is repository class

```
suspend fun getCurrencyFile:Response<CurrencyAPIResponse>{
    return currencyService.getCurrencyFile()
}
```

then in your view model class

```
    Coroutines.main {
            try{
               val response = repository.getCurrencyFile()
               if(response.isSuccessful){
                   //response.body is your data
                }
            }catch(Exception){}
     }
```

if you are not using the repository class you can skip the second step and directly call the service in viewmodel class,
The Coroutines code is

```
object Coroutines {
    fun main(work:suspend (()->Unit)) =
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            work()
        }
}
```